# How to fix Angular replace bootstrap error when ng serve

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I get following error on 'ng serve' command. I have just pulled this from git, deleted node_modules and package-lock file, ran npm install and then ng serve. I've no idea what this means and nobody else seemed to have this issue before

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createUniqueName' of undefined
at 
...\Web\Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\transformers\replace_bootstrap.js:54:50
 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at standardTransform 
(...\Web\Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\transformers\replace_bootstrap.js:32:32)
at transformer (...\Web\Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\transformers\make_transform.js:17:25)
```

replace_bootstrap.js:54:50 looks like this:

```
const idPlatformBrowser = ts.factory.createUniqueName('__NgCli_bootstrap_');
```

replace_bootstrap.js:32:32 is this:

```
 entryModuleIdentifiers.forEach(entryModuleIdentifier => {
        // Figure out if it's a `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` call.
        if (!(entryModuleIdentifier.parent
            && entryModuleIdentifier.parent.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.CallExpression)) {
            return;
        }
        const callExpr = entryModuleIdentifier.parent;
        if (callExpr.expression.kind !== ts.SyntaxKind.PropertyAccessExpression) {
            return;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe something wrong with your `node_moduels` and I dont think you should remove `package-lock.json`. Try pull the project again from git and remove `node_modules` this way and then install:

```
  rm -rf node_modules

   npm install
```

It will remove your node_modules/ folder and then reinstall the dependencies from package.json.

Here is an explanation about `package-lock.json` file and why you should use the existing one:[Commit and do not delete package-lock.json](https://siderite.dev/blog/npm-gotcha-commit-and-do-not-delete.html/)

From site:

> A new developer comes and gets the project from source control. They use npm
> install and see that everything works perfectly, because the packages
> restored are the exact same versions as the ones restored for the
> original developer. But now they think "who committed
> package-lock.json? Don't they know it's redundant?" so they remove it
> from source control. Three months later another developer comes and
> runs npm install on the source from the code repository, only nothing
> works anymore. The versions that were downloaded are, depending on
> what is specified in package.json, the latest version of the
> dependency or maybe a version similar, but with a different minor
> version, and with the dependencies that the developers thought best
> for that particular version.